# The Make and Shell Command Option in g77

Tags: makefile, g77

What do the `make` and `shell` option mean in g77? For example, if I have the following script in my Makefile:

```
FC = g77
FFLAGS = -O2 -mno-cygwin
LDFLAGS =
CD = cd
LN = ln
LNFLAGS = -s
MAKE = /bin/make
RM = rm
RMFLAGS = -f
SHELL = /bin/sh
```

Does this mean that `make` operation needs to make use of `/bin/make.exe`?

On a side note: when I run the compilation, using the above command line, I got an error:

> /bin/sh: line 4: Making: command not
>   found

Not sure whether the two are related.

Edit: This is my Makfile:

```
arpacklib:
    @( \
    for f in $(DIRS); \
    do \
        $(CD) $$f; \
        $(ECHO) Making lib in $$f; \
        $(MAKE) $(PRECISIONS); \
        $(CD) ..; \
    done );
    $(RANLIB) $(ARPACKLIB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just variables holding the location of programs on your computer. There will probably be rules like `$(SHELL) a_shell_script.sh` using these variables. The `FC`, `CD`, `LN` and `RM` are similar, they just don't have the path explicitly listed. Having programs as variables makes it simple to change them, for example if you want to use a different version.

Your error looks like the shell is trying to run the command `Making`. A possible cause is there is an undefined variable in front of this, eg a rule

```
all:
    $(ECHO) Making something
```

which would expand to `Making something` when run instead of `echo Making something`. Without seeing the relevant line that's the best I can think of.

Comment: Question updated. In the light of your answer I can *guess* why I was getting the error. But any idea on how to fix the above `$(ECHO)` line?

Comment: Simply define `ECHO = echo` with the other variables.

Comment: Add that line to the list of variables from your first example in your makefile, eg after `SHELL = /bin/sh`.